# "Â" unable to read from html file

Tags: python, html, character-encoding, google-colaboratory

I was trying to read a file that contains something like "Ordinary of Â£0 each " but when I printed "Â" is missing i.e I got " 0 Ordinary of £0 each ". Below is my python code

```
file1 = open(path+files[i]+".txt.html", 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines()
for line in Lines: # read each line seperately
        print("line",line)
```

Please help

Comment: Could you check the encoding of that file? (Digging up Python way to do it right now. If you're on a GNU/Linux system, use the `file` command).

Comment: Try running that code from IDLE and see if that helps.  I'm pretty sure the encoding is ISO-8859-1 (maybe chardet could help here) and your terminal doesn't support that encoding#

Comment: Probably a mix-up between UTF-8 and ISO-8859 encodings. The UTF-8 bytes for the pound sign (`£`) are C2 A3. In ISO-8859-1, the C2 byte is the character `Â`, and A3 is `£`.

Comment: How are you viewing the contents of the file?

Comment: am running this code in google colab

Comment: The fact that you see two characters when you view the data, but Python prints only one, suggests to me that the data is UTF-8 encoded, and Python is handling it correctly.  However the tool that you are using to _view_ the data is assuming a different encoding, and so you see two characters because '£' encoded as UTF-8 consists of two bytes, and your viewing tool is interpreting them as separate characters.  So in summary your Python code is fine.